# $A × (B-C) = (A × B)-(A × C)$. Is the statement true or false?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

If it's true, prove it, if not give specific sets $A,B,C,D.$

My try: I tried to work with some sets and the statement turned out to be true. But when Im using identities, I do not know how to manipulate the RHS

- for the LHS: $( A \times B ) \cap ( A \times C' ) $
- but RHS: ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated ! thank you

Comment: Typesetting hint:  you probably want \setminus instead of / so A \setminus B gives $A \setminus B$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to prove, that $A\times (B-C)=(A\times B)-(A\times C)$

So let $(x,y)\in A\times (B-C)$. Then $x\in A$ and $y\in B$ and $y\notin C$.
Hence $(x,y)\in A\times B$ and $(x,y)\notin A\times C$ and we conclude $(x,y)\in (A\times B)-(A\times C)$.

Go through this proof one by one. If you struggle with one point, go and look at the definition of the symbols.

Now let $(x,y)\in (A\times B)-(A\times C)$. So $(x,y)\in (A\times B)$ and $(x,y)\notin (A\times C)$.

$(x,y)\in A\times B$. Hence $x\in A$ and $y\in B$.

Since $(x,y)\notin A\times C$ and we know, that $x\in A$ we have that $y\notin C$.

So $y\in B-C$ and we conclude $(x,y)\in A\times (B-C)$.

Indeed both sets are equal.